# Wiring an IC for VGA switcher

Tags: microcontroller, power, switches, schematics

Original schematic:

[image]

Here is the goal switch between two VGA outputs from one source VGA input. 
Parts list:
1 SPDT switch for switching between A or B video outputs.
2 CBT3244AD IC chips (here's the datasheet)  http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/CBT3244A.pdf
The VCC on the IC chip is that the 5volts power? How can I wire the IC so I don't have to have more than the one switch?
Are the enables connected to the switch and ground? Basically both enables are connected on the outside pair of the SPDT and the ground is on the inside line?

Possible wiring of switch?[image]
Or is this the proper way to go[image]
Using a DPDT IS THIS THE CORRECT DIAGRAM? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes VCC on the chip is for 5V; 4.5 to 5.5V is the recommended operating range in the datasheet. The chip you referenced has 8 inputs and 8 outputs; effectively 8 channels. They are grouped into two sets of four channels, where each set of four can be enabled independently via separate active-low output enable signals. That means you connect either output enable signal to GND in order to enable the associated channels, or to 5V to disable the associated channels.

Now VGA, as I understand it, has at least 5 signals that need to get to a monitor: HSYNC, VSYNC, Red, Green, and Blue. It has 7 if you include the EDID lines (SDA and SCL essentially). If you want to route those 5 signals to one of two different places, I don't see a way to do that with only 8 channels - I think you need at least 10, so you could do it with two chips.

Incidentally, there is at least one chip on the market that seems like it's particularly well suited to the task you are describing: Texas Instruments [TS5V522C](http://www.ti.com/product/ts5v522c). Another one would be [NXP NX5DV715](http://www.nxp.com/products/logic/analog_switches/NX5DV715HF.html).

Here's how you should wire your switch (two ways):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr2nqK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Either way will work, one is not better than the other. Here /OE1 refers to the ganged output enable for chip #1 and /OE2 refers to the ganged output enable for chip #2. If you had a DPDT switch you could do this (no resistors required):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0QJzB.png)</sup>

Comment: by connecting the enables on both sides it acts as an 8 signal switch. So once one enable is activated it will also activate the other side as well. I'm am only using the RGBHV and ground wires from the VGA

Comment: @DanielKimbril the point is you want to reach two destinations, so you need at least 10 outputs, and you've only got 8 using one chip...

Comment: @viatcu so if I run 5 volts to a switch and the enables of each to the outside of the SPDT switch would that activate the IC?

Comment: @DanielKimbril the IC is always active so long as power is applied to VCC and GND on the chip... if the /OE signal is connected to GND it will pass the signals through the chip, if the /OE signal is connected to 5V it  will not pass the signals through the chip and the outputs will be set to high impedance.

Comment: Please updated picture in the question.

Comment: @DanielKimbril oh I see, you *are* using two chips... so the picture you've drawn would need like a 10k pull-down resistor to GND on each chip's /OE to make it work (or a 10k pull-up resistor to 5V if you wired the common pole to GND instead of 5V) otherwise when the switch is slid one way or the other, the opposite enable pin would be floating and that's an "undefined" state. If you had a double-pole / single throw switch, you could cross wire the outer poles and feed a separate common to each chip...

Comment: p.s. I always get poles and throws confused so forgive me if I mixed that up.

Comment: I've uploaded a second picture. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @DanielKimbril not quite, I've added a schematic representation of what I mean to my answer.

Comment: Uploaded pic using a DPDT @vicatcu

Comment: using the DPDT don't I want the one IC connected to ground when the other is connected to power thus turning off 1 IC while the the other is in use?

Comment: @DanielKimbril yes, sorry I've updated the schematic in my answer for DPDT.